# best way (or easiest) to detect collision?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

i actually can't find a way to do that easily, all the tutorials i find on the internet are too complicated for me or won't work.

could someone show me (in a very basic way, not a whole program) how to detect collision?

Comment: If you want to get into collision detection you should look into ray tracing.
But if you want a simple solution you should probably cheat, and just check to see if the object is with in a certain proximity of the location.  In your update loop you need to approximate the size of the object and check if the x and y cooridnate are within a certain box

Comment: I guess, it would be easier to help you, if you give us more information. It depends on your design, the sahpes you use etc. If you have a tile-based game , it might be enough to have a 2D-Array and simply check if there is a value at that specific position. Otherwhise you may have to do some overlap test for different kind of shapes.

Comment: I want to make a flappy bird game, and I want to detect collision between pipes and the bird

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using bounding boxes for initial detection.
If the areas of the bounding boxes are overlapping at all, check for a collision within the objects by using the same method as bounding boxes, just on a much more accurate scale.